# Rails 4 Error: NoMethodError undefined method `to_model' for true:TrueClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, nomethoderror

If I put something like this...

```
#button
    = link_to(@item.is_active = true) do
        .btn Publish
```

into my haml view, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Jobs#show
undefined method `to_model' for true:TrueClass
```

I am just trying to assign `true` to the `is_active` column of `@item`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: link_to will not change is_active value, you have to create 'update' action in JobsController, pass the @item to this action, then change its is_active value (in your example, link_to is trying to find 'show' action in JobsController)

Comment: @Moamen Naanou That sounds right. I tried what you suggested but I struggle on accessing the controller action from that button or is the action itself wrong? `def set_active
        @job.is_active = true
        @job.save
    end`

Comment: Combined with `= link_to("", :controller => "jobs", :action => "set_active", :id => @job)` it just does not work... (database gets not updated)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want a link_to here.  I would use a `form_tag` for this.

Comment: And how shout I exactly do that?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag